Prevent system shutdown while task scheduler task is running
How can I create a task in Windows task scheduler that prevents (automatic) system reboots while it is running? I want the task to finish before any restarts are performed.
Note: I'm aware that one can physically always shut down a computer, but I want to prevent this scenario at least during "normal operation" of the computer.

REad following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/454699/disable-or-change-ctrl-alt-del-for-kiosk-mode

You can call the win32 api and create a shutdown block in the script while it is running, though this requires administrator access for the task manager calling the powershell script.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate
Inside your script, you can put your code after you create the shutdown block, then destroy the block one the script finalizes.
$code = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsControl {
    public class Shutdown {
            [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(IntPtr WindowHandle, string Reason);

            [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(IntPtr WindowHandle);

    }
}
'@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code
$process = get-process -pid $pid
if ($p.MainWindowHandle -ne 0) {
    [WindowsControl.Shutdown]::ShutdownBlockReasonCreate($process.MainWindowHandle,"Script <scriptname> currently running")
    <#  
        Code wrapped inside here
    #>
    [WindowsControl.Shutdown]::ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy($process.MainWindowHandle)
}

